# How to use wildcard for ansible output

Tags: variables, ansible, wildcard

I am trying to use wildcard for my ansible variable but it seems like i cant manage to use it.

I have tried something from [here](https://gist.github.com/halberom/af695bc02fbe19a9e4d2d6667300bb92) but still the same.

the ansible output

```
"reboot_required": false,
"updates": {
    "0720a128-90b1-4b21-a8cf-3c5c86239435": {
        "kb": [
            "2267602"
        ],
        "installed": false,
        "id": "0720a128-90b1-4b21-a8cf-3c5c86239435",
        "categories": [
            "Definition Updates",
            "Windows Defender"
        ],
        "title": "Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.297.412.0)"
    },
    "60bbf4af-afd3-45fe-aad2-6d72beddeba2": {
        "kb": [
            "4509475"
        ],
        "installed": false,
        "id": "60bbf4af-afd3-45fe-aad2-6d72beddeba2",
        "categories": [
            "Updates",
            "Windows Server 2016"
        ],
        "title": "2019-06 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4509475)"
```

I am trying to get the title, or id

```
- name: debug
  debug:  
    msg: "{{ item.updates.*.id }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ result }}"
```

appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the *ansible output* above is stored in the variable *result* the tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    id_list: "{{ result.updates|
                 json_query('*.id')
                 }}"
- debug:
    var: id_list
```

give the list of *id* (similar *titles*)

```
  id_list:
  - 0720a128-90b1-4b21-a8cf-3c5c86239435
  - 60bbf4af-afd3-45fe-aad2-6d72beddeba2
```

And the tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ result.updates|
                 json_query('*.{ id: id, title: title }')
                 }}"
- debug:
    var: my_list
```

give the list of the *id, title* hashes

```
  my_list:
  - id: 0720a128-90b1-4b21-a8cf-3c5c86239435
    title: Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.297.412.0)
  - id: 60bbf4af-afd3-45fe-aad2-6d72beddeba2
    title: 2019-06 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4509475)
```

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard he's using in the example that you linked is apart of the json_query filter. He's piping to the json_query filter and then using the wildcard as part of that syntax.

```
results | json_query('[].block_device_mapping.*.snapshot_id')
```

You're not using json_query in your example and therefore, this syntax is not available and won't work.

Try piping your results to json_query and then including the path that you want to get to. If {{ results }} is already created you can leave off the with_items and go with something like:

```
{{ results | json_query('updates.*.id') }}
```

I'm guessing here at the exact syntax but you definitely have to start with json_query.

To figure out the exact syntax you want, start small piping to json_query and then grabbing the top most element(updates, in your case), adding pieces to the filter until you've narrowed it down to the information you want. I've linked to a pathfinder below that helps.

Reference:

- [json_query filter documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)
- [json_query documentation](https://json-query-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [jsonpath finder](https://jsonpath.com/) to help you figure stuff out easier.

edit: The syntax in the first part of the answer from Vladimir looks way sexier than what I'm guessing at. Try his syntax to get to what works, use my answer to understand what's wrong. Then mark him as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. I have not tested it though.

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item|first }}:{{ item[item|first].title }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ result.updates }}"
```